# Appium on App Center can't switch between iOS and Android (Java)

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, visual-studio-app-center-test

When I write appium tests specifically to run on App Center (and therefore must use the custom 'Enhanced Driver'), it looks like I can only declare `driver` as either an `EnhancedAndroidDriver` type, or an `EnhancedIOSDriver` type.

```
    public EnhancedAndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
//    public EnhancedIOSDriver<MobileElement> driver; <----- can't declare same variable twice

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() throws IOException {
        String PLATFORM_NAME = System.getenv("XTC_PLATFORM");
        if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
            EnhancedAndroidDriver<MobileElement> androiddriver = Factory.createAndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver = androiddriver;
        } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("iOS")) {
            EnhancedIOSDriver<MobileElement> iosdriver = Factory.createIOSDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver = iosdriver;  <---- compiler error, wrong type
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

I want to run a simple test in a single file that will run on both platforms, but it seems I must choose either android or ios for that file to run on. How do I avoid duplicating all my test files? I am using react native and my app is basically identical on both platforms. I have done something similar with the regular AppiumDriver.

Any suggestions to programmatically switch which type 'EnhancedIOS/AndroidDriver' the variable `driver` refers to in Java??

With the regular AppiumDriver, I can do this:

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() throws IOException {
    if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
       driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("iOS")) {
       driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    return driver;
}
```

And then use the driver in the tests generically. But it seems impossible to take this approach with the App Center Enhanced drivers because they don't share a common type (or I don't know enough about Java to figure it out). Is there any way to work around this??

Comment: according to the devices(added devices in appcenter) you are running the test case on. The desired capabilities are picked from appcenter and populated. So, yes you cannot use the same driver for both android and ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an Interface that wrapped the driver, which instantiated and operated on the platform specific driver for each driver method I use, and allowed me to use the common name driver to refer to it throughout the rest of the test framework.

I passed in the platform name to the Interface when I instantiated the interface. The platform name was read as an environment variable I set in the App Center branch build settings.